# Lightmap UV generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, light

I've had a great interest in lightmap baking for quite a while now, but before I can start working on it I need a method to generate lightmap UV's for meshes automatically, and I have a hard time finding algorithms for it.

Currently I've found these articles:
https://members.loria.fr/Bruno.Levy/papers/LSCM_SIGGRAPH_2002.pdf
http://hhoppe.com/ssp.pdf

I saw this article floating around a few times as well but sadly it's off the air and the wayback machine doesn't go back in time far enough for proper results:
http://www.loria.fr/~levy/Papers/2003/eg2003_light_textures.pdf

I'm not very picky and because I'm new to this topic I would love to see easier but still viable algorithms for the UV generation of lightmaps, does anybody here know other good examples of these algorithms?

Comment: There is a multitude of parametrization methods and there is no one perfect solution for all scenarios. Can you say something about your models? Might they already have a parametrization?

Comment: The models are very bare-bones, only containing vertex data of the normals, postions and diffuse texture UVs (and possibly colours)

Comment: Then use the diffuse texture UVs.

Comment: They overlap/fall outside the texture range sometimes so they aren't useful for lightmap textures